# Triggering event for SignalR

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, signalr

I am using SignalR to update client-side when data is changing on the backend. The data can be either from SQL Server or NoSQL DB.

What I am doing now is: I have a timer on the backend that constantly is trying to check whether there is a change in the DB and if it detects it then I allow SignalR to update the client-side.

I find this approach not good: the timer's interval value can't be really small e.g. even with 1 second I have a huge load on the DB. Besides, it's not real-time and even 1 second is too big. Additionally, that it's quite difficult to detect a DB change if it's not about adding a new record, but calculating some hash for all the records every 1 second or even less is surely not an option.

I think I used to read about another approach that is based on some event triggered either by the DB or by something else, but I can't remember this.
So I was wondering if somebody could advise me of a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid we need to take different actions for different scenarios on this case.

As you mentioned that your data may come from SQL server and nosql db. So I think the scenario should like:

1. You write code to update the data in both of the database, if so, you can write the calling signalr code after the updating data code, so that you are no need to using trigger.
2. Based on the scenario 1 as well, if the database you used support using stored procedure, you may also try to find the possibility of writing stored procedure to call the signalr code.
3. You may also check if the databases you used have event like "data_onchange_event", [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.onchange?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#applies-to) is related to this scenario. I mean if the data stored in the database updated, your database will send an event, you can then write custom code to capture these event and then call signalr.
4. If you can't or don't write code to update your databases, then you may only using external trigger to monitor the database, but just like you mentioned in the question, it doesn't support high performance because of huge load on the DB. It's based on the database but not the external trigger.